# MailMessage smtpClient not working after release

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, mailmessage

The following code is working fine when debugging with *localhost* but not after I release to the web-server.

```
protected void SendMail()
    {

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add("xxxxxx@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = ddlSubject.Text;

        mailMessage.Body = "<b>Sender Title: </b> " + ddlTitle.SelectedItem.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender First Name: </b> " + txtFName.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Last Name: </b> " + txtLName.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Email: </b> " + txtEmail.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Phone: </b> " + txtPhone.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Address: </b> " + txtAddress.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Suburb: </b> " + ddlSuburbs.SelectedItem.Text + "<br/>"
            + "<b>Sender Message: </b> " + contactMessage.InnerText + "<br/>";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        lblConfirmation.Text = "Thank you " + ddlTitle.SelectedItem.Text + " " + txtFName.Text.ToUpper() + " " + txtLName.Text.ToUpper() + " for contacting us. We will try to get back to you ASAP";
    }
```

**NOTE** The website is using SSL.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any firewall rules in place or whether there is a proxy on the production server?

Comment: I am using goDaddy hosting services

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking them whether they are blocking outgoing traffic using that port.

Comment: They have not, Just enquired.

Comment: What exception is reported by the code? Can you send using an outbound SMTP server other than GMail?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure port=25.

```
  try 
  { 
           MailMessage msg = new MailMessage ();
           MailAddress fromAdd = new MailAddress("fromemail@email.com");
           msg.[To].Add("toemail@email.com");
           msg.Subject = "Choose Session Members";
           msg.From = fromAdd;
           msg .IsBodyHtml = true;
           msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
           msg .BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
           msg.Body = "<center><table><tr><td><h1>Your Message</h1><br/><br/></td></tr>";
           msg.Body = msg.Body + "</table></center>";
           SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient ("smtp.yourserver.com", "25");
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
           smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourname@yourserver.com", "password");
           smtpClient .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           smtpClient.Send(msg);
           smtpClient.Dispose();
        }
    catch (exception ex){
        Label1.Text  = ex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Not working, I have also enabled access from less secured apps in my email getting this error message:  System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.